# How do I share Protocol Buffer .proto files between multiple repositories

Tags: python, node.js, git, protocol-buffers

We are considering using [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for communicating between a python & a node.js service that each live in their own repos.

Since the `.proto` files must be accessible to both repos, how should we share the `.proto` files?

We are currently considering:

1. Creating a repo for all our `.proto` files, and making it a git subtree of all our services
2. Creating a repo for all our `.proto` files, publishing both a private python module and private node module on push, and requiring the modules from the respective services
3. Creating a repo for all our `.proto` files, and specifying the repository as the destination of a `pip` / `npm` package

What is the standard way to share `.proto` files between repositories?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This depends on your development process.

A git subtree / submodule seems like a sensible solution for most purposes. If you had more downstream projects, publishing a ready-made module would make sense, as then the protobuf generator wouldn't be needed for every project.

Comment: This is what we're leaning towards at the moment. Still wish there were better documented best-practices for this. Seems like a fairly common use case

Comment: Do you keep each proto file in it's own repository, then include the needed proto repository or do you keep them all in one repository and include all proto files even if you don't need them in given service?

Answer (score 3):

We, in the same situation, used 3 repos: server-side was written in c++, client-side in actionscript 3, and protobufs was in the third, and was used both of them. For a big team, and big project I think it was a good choice.

Comment: How did you actually 'use' the repo holding the protobufs?

Comment: Just like any other repo - make changes and commit them. Then, for example, on client-side, project was compiled with ant scripts, which firstly transpile .proto files into actionscript classes, and after that compile whole project.