# what is the best practice to share protobuf models across multiple github repositories

Tags: github, protocol-buffers

I have a github repo called `data-models` that contains all the `.proto` files. I have other repositories (written in python, c++) that will be using these protobuf models. The protobuf models in `data-model` depends on/imports other models within the same `data-model` repo. Without having to duplicate these `.proto` files across multiple repositories, what is the best way to have my other 2 repos access these models and successfully compile them with `protoc`?

Comment: Related or maybe even duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862101/how-do-i-share-protocol-buffer-proto-files-between-multiple-repositories

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether it's *the* best practice but it's my practice and it works.

I maintain one GitHub repo for each Protocol Buffer `package`.

So, if your `data-models` were `package foo` then I would have a GitHub repo for `foo`. The GitHub repo need not be called `foo` but it should contain a root folder called `foo`.

The Protocol Buffer `package` hierarchy would then be replicated under the GitHub repo's `foo` folder, i.e. sources in `package foo.bar` would be in the repo's `foo/bar` folder etc.

You then have alternatives. You can leave it to your users to generate stubs. Or, you can use a CI (e.g. GitHub Actions) to generate stubs in various languages whenever changes are made to the Protocol Buffer sources.

Example: Google does this for its services Protocol Buffers definitions. See [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) where its Protocol Buffer sources are rooted on a package `google` and represented in the repo's folder [`google`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google)

The advantage of this approach are that it encourages a clear distinction (for both you the developer and your users) between gRPC implementations and interface definitions (with stubs) including independent versioning.

Comment: sorry if this might be a noob question here: but are you saying to replicate the `foo` package to my python/C++ repos and then compile stubs for each language?

Comment: No apology necessary. You must have the stubs locally in order to compile them into your code. Keeping the Protocol Buffer sources **and** generated stubs as a distinct repo|folder encourages a good separation. You will need to clone the Protocol Buffer repo locally either to use stubs generated automatically in it or to (re)generate the stubs yourself and then most languages will provide a way for you to import the stubs.